# How to convert a vector<vector<int>> to int** without rebuilding the array?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl

I don't like to use pointers too much and I'm always using stl tools. I've gotten into this situation where I need to pass a int** to a third_party function that needs to work with a 2d array of ints. I have written the following function that creates a vector of int*s to do the job. My question is that is it safe to do this assuming that the third_party function does not change the structure of the array and just accesses the data entries. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the function def:

```
void ConvertVectorVectorToIntStarStar(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v,vector<int*>* a) {
  assert(a);
  int n = v.size();
  a->resize(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    (*a)[i] = (int*)(&v[i][0]);
}
```

and this is the usage:

```
  vector<int*> p;
  ConvertVectorVectorToIntStarStar(v, &p);
  int** a = &p[0];
  third_party_function(a);
```

Comment: You may use `v.data()` instead of `&v[0]`.

Comment: @Jarod42: That's only in C++11, the question is tagged as C++.

Comment: `&v[0]` is illegal if `v.empty()`, so if you lack `.data()` you should `v.empty()?NULL:&v[0]`, which is annoying, or upgrade your compiler, which is rainbows.

Comment: OP, do you have C++11 support?  Are the arrays 'jagged' or all the same size?  Do they vary at run time -- how do they end?

Comment: @Yakk no I don't have 11. I don't care about the case when v is empty cause that won't happen.

Comment: SO: ask 3 questions, get two answers, one of which is to a question you did not ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the cast, something isn't right:

```
(*a)[i] = (int*)(&v[i][0]);
```

I *guess* this should really read

```
(*a)[i] = const_cast<int*>(v[i].data());
```

Otherwise the code looks OK and it should work: the elements in a `std::vector<T>` are contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

> How to convert a `vector<vector<int>>` to `int**`

**You can't simply convert it.**

The internal layout of a vector of `vector<int>` is just mind-bogglingly incompatible with an array of `int*`. :-)

Here are your types:

```
vector<vector<int>> v{{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 } };
int (*a)[] = { new int[3], new int[3], new int[3] };
```

The first thing you'll notice is that `a` is an `int (*)[]` rather than an `int**`. When you use `a` it'll decay to an `int**`; an `int[][]` *would not do this*.

Let's get our first-level pointers:

```
vector<int>* ptr1 = &v[0];
int**        ptr2 = &a[0];
```

Now let's look at the storage:

- `ptr1[0]` is a `vector<int>`
- `ptr2[0]` is a `int*`

Clearly, these are not in any way the same sort of thing. Without even needing to go any further, the memory layout is already different. This means you cannot just "get" an `int**` to the vector's data.

---

**However**, if you don't mind constructing the outermost "indexing" array from scratch, then your approach is basically sound. It's just not the zero-step process you seem to be after.

---

Instead of all this, my suggestion would be wrapping a `vector<int>` (with length Width × Height) with 2D-index access semantics. You would then be able to play with an `int*` to the entire data buffer if you wished.

With thanks to *Freenode ##c++*:

```
template<typename T>
struct matrix
{
   matrix(unsigned m, unsigned n)
      : m(m), n(n), vs(m*n)
   {}

   T& operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j)
   {
      return vs[i + m * j];
   }

private:
   unsigned m, n;
   std::vector<T> vs;
};

/* column-major/opengl: vs[i + m * j], row-major/c++: vs[n * i + j] */
```

Comment: I have created a test case and looks like this works.

Comment: You don't have to fully rebuild the array, you can just make an array of `int*` pointing to the contents of vectors, isn't that what he's doing?

Comment: @user2345215: Well I suppose if you construct the outermost array from scratch then yes, but that's a single rebuilding step.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi: I think your "without rebuilding the array" requirement confused me. I can see now that you _are_ satisfied with performing _some_ array reconstruction, even if not on the base data. That's a different beast and now I'm not really sure what your problem is...

Comment: Is it not ok to assume that vector elements are contiguous in memory?

Comment: The indexing adapter won't solve the OP's problem. He is passing the 2D array to a 3rd party library, which cannot access the adapter.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi: They are. The issue is not the innermost dimension, it's the outer one. Your code re-constructs the outermost dimension from scratch using pointers to the actual vector data, which is fine. But if you wanted to "get" an `int**` from the outermost vector with no re-organisation at all, you wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the actual problem is that the vector<vector<int>> can be very large in the order of gigabytes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree with you. That was what I first tried.

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi: It would depend a bit on whether you have "many inner elements per outer element", or "many outer elements with few inner elements", but overall if you have gigabytes than having all those inner vectors is not going to be very efficient. I would definitely look at a matrix wrapper over 1D storage.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the current code …

```
void ConvertVectorVectorToIntStarStar(const std::vector<std::vector<int> >& v,vector<int*>* a) {
  assert(a);
  int n = v.size();
  a->resize(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    (*a)[i] = (int*)(&v[i][0]);
}
```

I suggest that you do …

```
vector<int*> IntStarStarFrom( std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v)
{
    int const n = static_cast<int>( v.size() );
    assert( n > 0 );
    vector<int*> a( n );

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        assert( v[i].size() > 0 );
        a[i] = &v[i][0];
    }
    return std::move( a );
}
```

Disclaimer: off-the cuff code, not touched by compiler’s hands.

The **assertions** express the relevant safety concerns.

A vector’s buffer is guaranteed contiguous, but IIRC it’s Undefined Behavior to index the vector when its size is 0.

The usage code, reworked to use the suggested function replacement:

```
vector<int*> p = IntStarStarFrom( v );
int** const a = &p[0];
third_party_function( a );
```

Or as [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) remarked in a comment, you can now do this in a single line of code:

```
third_party_function(IntStarStarFrom(v).data());
```

Comment: You could turn the call into a one-liner with this approach: `third_party_function(IntStarStarFrom(v).data());`

Comment: @MarkRansom: thanks! i didn't even think of that, only thinking of the effect on the original code. adding to answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vt;
// some code with vt..

std::vector<int *> vtp;
for (const std::vector<int> &vtr : vt)
    vtp.push_back(const_cast<int *>(vtr.data()));
```

I haven't tested but I think I works well